# C# MySQL запрос-ответ

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Можно ли после выполнения запроса MySQL (напр. INSERT), получить ответ в C# и выполнить метод?

Это нужно для того чтобы обновить таблицу в DGV у пользователя, когда другой выполнит запрос.

P.S. Приложение настольное (WinForms), работающее на разных компьютерах, которое подключается к серверу (пока что XAMPP) через строку подключения; не понимаю как это еще объяснить.

Comment: Какой ответ вас интересует?

Comment: Выполняйте запрос и не важно какой ответ придет - просто обновляете грид.

Comment: Любой, например true или false, главное чтобы метод сработал.
Есть же fileSystemWatcher, который отслеживает изменения в папке. Наподобие этого, только отследить изменения в БД.

Comment: Но ведь DVG обновится только у одного пользователя, у другого будет все так же.

Comment: Давайте уточним: приложения работают на разных компьютерах. И одно должно узнавать об изменениях в БД, сделанных другим. Так?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: это вообще в корне меняет дело, такое надо крупными буквами в вопросе писать. Есть много разных варианто как такое сделать. У вас сервер есть какой то? Или вы няпрямую в БД цепляетесь с клиентов?

Comment: это вообще что? Настольное приложение? Веб приложение?

Comment: п.с. ксли пишете кому то ответ, указывайте его ник вот так @Алексей

Comment: @tym32167 Дополнил в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сама СУБД MySQL, насколько мне известно, не имеет средств оповещения клиентов. Поэтому ваши приложения должны периодически производить опрос (long polling) базы данных на предмет выяснения, были ли изменения. Но это неэффективно.

Более правильным решением будет обращаться из приложений не напрямую к БД, а написать некий сервер. Этот сервер будет принимать запросы из ваших приложений, вносить изменения в БД и сообщать другим приложениям о наличии изменений.

Как вариант, можно обойтись без выделенного сервера. Тогда все приложения должны напрямую взаимодействовать друг с другом. То есть приложение после внесения изменений в БД должно само сообщить другим об этом.

---

Конкретная реализация всех этих способов зависит от множества факторов: где установлена СУБД, связь осуществляется по локальной сети или через интернет и т. п.